# Get output of the updated row only if the updated row is not null?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am having issues when trying to get the result of an updated row, the query that I use as shown below update a certain row when it meets a specific conditions,however, and though the conditions are not met, the Update query output gets the value "0" rather than NULL, Is there any tips so that I can fix this in the same query,with that said, I'm trying to avoid the use of other queries because it's within a method that has to optimised the most possible.

```
SqlCommand loadbonus = new SqlCommand();
loadbonus.Connection = conn;
loadbonus.CommandText = "UPDATE Client SET [Restant Bonus]=[Restant Bonus]-(SELECT SUM([Prix Total]) FROM Comptoir WHERE [N° Comptoir]='" + tabcontrol.SelectedIndex + "'),[Total Consommé]=[Total Consommé]+(SELECT SUM([Prix Total]) FROM Comptoir WHERE [N° Comptoir]='" + tabcontrol.SelectedIndex + "') OUTPUT INSERTED.[Restant Bonus] WHERE [Code Client]=@CodeClient AND [Bonus Fidélité]='1'";
loadbonus.Parameters.Add("@CodeClient", SqlDbType.Int).Value = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(clientcodecomptoire.Text) ? DBNull.Value : (object)Convert.ToInt32(clientcodecomptoire.Text);

int restantbonus = Convert.ToInt32(loadbonus.ExecuteScalar());
if (restantbonus <= 0)
{// here is the issue! the left side of the If statement can containt there "0" value for both a "0" value and a Null value}
```

Comment: Careful, that query looks open to injection; you really want to parametrise that query.

Comment: @Larnu the non parametised inputs are not and can not be set manualy, so why be carful?

Comment: Why not use a stored procedure to control the update?

Comment: @WEI_DBA read about that, to be honnest I really don't know how to do it, and don't have time to learn how to do it either.

Comment: Because not using parameters in your queries is a terrible practice. It is so easy to parameterize them that not doing it is simply laziness or negligence. It takes far less effort to do it correctly then it takes to defend not doing it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a stored procedure has many benefits. It starts to get you a separate data layer from the application. It is also parameterized so you can avoid sql injection.

Here is what your procedure might look like.

```
create procedure Client_Update
(
    @NComptoir int
) as

    set nocount on;

    declare @MyTotal int;

    SELECT @MyTotal = SUM([Prix Total]) 
    FROM Comptoir 
    WHERE [N° Comptoir] = @NComptoir;

    UPDATE Client
    SET [Restant Bonus] = [Restant Bonus] - @MyTotal
        ,[Total Consommé] = [Total Consommé] + @MyTotal;

    select @MyTotal;
```

Then to use in dotnet you should change up a few things. You need to use the USING statement around objects like commands and connections to ensure they get properly disposed of. You already have a connection object so I am leaving that to you.

```
using (SqlCommand loadbonus = new SqlCommand("Client_Update", conn))
{
    loadbonus.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    loadbonus.Parameters.Add("@NComptoir", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tabcontrol.SelectedIndex;
    int restantbonus = Convert.ToInt32(loadbonus.ExecuteScalar());
    if (restantbonus <= 0)
    {
    }
}
```

The issue I see though is that you add a parameter (@Seuil) in your code but it is not part of the update statement. And since you are setting the value to the text of a textbox it will get 0 when set to an empty string. That is because it is being converted to an int. I have no idea what the purpose of that parameter is though because it is not part of your query.

I hope this helps at least give you a push in the right direction.